# View mode for specific bundle

Tags: 7, entities

Drupal 7 makes it quite easy to create a new view mode (see [this tutorial](http://mearra.com/blogs/juha-niemi/drupal-7-custom-node-view-modes) for instance), but is there a way to define a view mode that is only available for a specific bundle (content type)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.

View modes are specified per entity type, not bundle, as [hook_entity_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info/7) shows.

It is also not possible to define extra fields which are only available for a specific bundle/view mode combination, only per bundle.

Comment: OK, I sort of expected this answer. Thanks for confirming that it can't be done.

Comment: How about specifying it for entity, but make it enabled by default only for a bundle (say your custom content type), and leave disabled for other content types?

Answer (score 1):

The Drupal contrib module [Entity View Mode](https://drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode) lets you create view modes and specify for which specific bundles: Article, Basic page, etc.

Comment: No, not really. Entity View Mode only lets you specify the bundles where the 'custom display settings' for the newly created view mode must be enabled initially. Regardless of the custom display settings, a view mode is available for all bundles of the entity type.